# How can I get Ubuntu 13.04 to work like it did before the Kernel update to Linux Image 3.8.0.19.30?

Tags: updates, kernel, 13.04, shutdown

I had successfully installed  Ubuntu 13.04 from a live USB by upgrading the previous version 12.10. I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows.

After installing Linux Image 3.8.0.19.**30**_i386.deb I was able to reboot the computer successfully only for the 1st time.

However, on the next reboot there was a problem with the booting as it did not automatically boot to  Ubuntu 13.04.

It now gives an error message that KVM is disabled by BIOS.

**Most Importantly I am unable to power down the computer by the GUI or by commands from the terminal.** I have to do a physical reboot or physically cut the power by switching off the UPS. (Error appended to this question). I can suspend the computer but cannot reboot it. Every time I click shutdown it goes to the 'Log out' screen.

The System Monitor shows that both the cores are running at around 80% even when just idling. It used to usually run between 5 to 25 % for regular tasks.

I can hear the fan whirring quite loudly ever since this problem started.

Now Ubuntu 13.04 does not recognize the Samsung monitor & has changed the resolution from 1440 x 900 to 1280 x 1024.

Unity has become painfully slow. The External HDD is not being recognized. Please help.

Would it be possible to run this OS without a fresh install?

Thanks.

```
----@-----:~$ sudo shutdown -h now
[sudo] password for -----: 
sudo: shutdown: command not found
```

Here is another error message that might help identify the problem:

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
Error in function:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the following lines are intact in your `/etc/sudoers` file

```
Defaults   env_reset
Defaults   secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

If these are not there, you can copy and paste these lines and save the file and then reboot.

After the reboot, you wont be facing this problem.

**Source:** http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=390742

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding so soon & for the link giving information about this. 

I did look for the file you mentioned “/etc/sudoers”. However, I only got this file named /etc/sudoers.d

The file named /etc/sudoers.d has a 958 bytes file, which is not opening on double click. Says file is of 'unknown type'.

Is that extra .d after sudoers OK? 

Please let me know how & where could I paste:
Defaults   env_reset
Defaults   secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

Does it have to pasted in the terminal? 
 
Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks folks. I did some digging around & found that because of frequent improper shutdowns of the computer due to some hardware problems (like frequent random shutdowns by a previous faulty UPS) there has been some damage (corruption) to different software. 

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 & everything is great. Thanks again.

Comment: The problem is solved & the question may be marked as answered. Thanks.